# Web API: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after successful communication with Siemens PLC device

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, webapi

My Project is used to read data from an Siemens 1500 PLC and visualize them via webpage. Therefore I've set up a Web API and wrote a function, which reads 34 bool variables and writes them to an array at a cyclic period. Within this function an AJAX request is send to the webserver of the CPU based on the structure of the official Siemens manual.
At the beginning the communication works, but after some time (between 2 minutes and 2 hours) the following request error occurs:

POST https://IP_PLC/api/jsonrpc net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE     jquery_3.6.0.js:10109

Afterwards sometimes the communication goes on, but most commonly this error repeats combined with other errors like:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://IP_PLC' form origin 'IP_live_Server_VS_Code' has been blocked by Cors policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status;

POST https://IP_PLC/api/jsonrpc net::ERR_FAILED    jquery_3.6.0.js:10109;

I've already varied the the cyclic period from 0.5 to 2 sec, traced the occupancy rate of the CPU and tried Firefox and Chrome as browser. I work with VS Code and the Live Server Extension, but also startet the webpage from the memory location. Same behaviour.

Every answer is welcome, thanks a lot !

These are the involved codes of my js files:

request.js:

```
function postJsonRPC(host, request, token, successCallback, errorCallBack) 
    {   
      if(host && request && (token || (request.method && request.method.toLowerCase().indexOf('api.login') != -1)))
      {
          var api = "https://"+ host +"/api/jsonrpc";
    
          // Send request
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: api,
              headers: {
                  'X-Auth-Token': token
              },
              data: JSON.stringify(request),
              dataType: "text",
              contentType: "application/json",
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  if(successCallback)
                      successCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  if(errorCallBack)
                      errorCallBack(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                  else {

                      console.log(errorThrown);
                  }                
              }
          });
          
          // Print request
          console.log("REQUEST: " + JSON.stringify(request));

      }
    }

function readValuesCU()
    {
    
        var request = [ 
          {
            id: "201",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[1]"}
          },
          {
            id: "202",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[2]"}
          },
          {
            id: "203",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[3]"}
          },
          {
            id: "204",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[4]"}
          },
          {
            id: "205",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[5]"}
          },
          {
            id: "206",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[6]"}
          },
          {
            id: "207",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[7]"}
          },
          {
            id: "208",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[8]"}
          },
          {
            id: "209",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[9]"}
          },
          {
            id: "210",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[10]"}
          },
          {
            id: "211",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[11]"}
          },
          {
            id: "212",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[12]"}
          },
          {
            id: "213",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[13]"}
          },
          {
            id: "214",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[14]"}
          },
          {
            id: "215",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[15]"}
          },
          {
            id: "216",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[16]"}
          },
          {
            id: "217",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[17]"}
          },
          {
            id: "218",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[18]"}
          },
          {
            id: "219",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[19]"}
          },
          {
            id: "220",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[20]"}
          },
          {
            id: "221",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[21]"}
          },
          {
            id: "222",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[22]"}
          },
          {
            id: "223",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[23]"}
          },
          {
            id: "224",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[24]"}
          },
          {
            id: "225",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[25]"}
          },
          {
            id: "226",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[26]"}
          },
          {
            id: "227",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[27]"}
          },
          {
            id: "228",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[28]"}
          },
          {
            id: "229",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[29]"}
          },
          {
            id: "230",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[30]"}
          },
          {
            id: "231",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[31]"}
          },
          {
            id: "232",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[32]"}
          },
          {
            id: "233",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[33]"}
          },
          {
            id: "234",
            jsonrpc: "2.0",
            method: "PlcProgram.Read",
            params: {var: "\"Web2Plc\".test[34]"}
          }
        ]; 
    
          postJsonRPC(hostAddress, request, userToken, function(data){
          
            for(var i = 0; i <= 33; i++)
            {
              values[i] = JSON.parse(data)[i]["result"];
            }

          console.log(values)
        });
        setTimeout(readValuesCU, 500);    
    }
```

reportet code from jQuery JavaScript Library v3.6.0:

```
jQuery.ajaxTransport( function( options ) {
    var callback, errorCallback;

    // Cross domain only allowed if supported through XMLHttpRequest
    if ( support.cors || xhrSupported && !options.crossDomain ) {
        return {
            send: function( headers, complete ) {
                var i,
                    xhr = options.xhr();

                xhr.open(
                    options.type,
                    options.url,
                    options.async,
                    options.username,
                    options.password
                );

                // Apply custom fields if provided
                if ( options.xhrFields ) {
                    for ( i in options.xhrFields ) {
                        xhr[ i ] = options.xhrFields[ i ];
                    }
                }

                // Override mime type if needed
                if ( options.mimeType && xhr.overrideMimeType ) {
                    xhr.overrideMimeType( options.mimeType );
                }

                // X-Requested-With header
                // For cross-domain requests, seeing as conditions for a preflight are
                // akin to a jigsaw puzzle, we simply never set it to be sure.
                // (it can always be set on a per-request basis or even using ajaxSetup)
                // For same-domain requests, won't change header if already provided.
                if ( !options.crossDomain && !headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] ) {
                    headers[ "X-Requested-With" ] = "XMLHttpRequest";
                }

                // Set headers
                for ( i in headers ) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader( i, headers[ i ] );
                }

                // Callback
                callback = function( type ) {
                    return function() {
                        if ( callback ) {
                            callback = errorCallback = xhr.onload =
                                xhr.onerror = xhr.onabort = xhr.ontimeout =
                                    xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

                            if ( type === "abort" ) {
                                xhr.abort();
                            } else if ( type === "error" ) {

                                // Support: IE <=9 only
                                // On a manual native abort, IE9 throws
                                // errors on any property access that is not readyState
                                if ( typeof xhr.status !== "number" ) {
                                    complete( 0, "error" );
                                } else {
                                    complete(

                                        // File: protocol always yields status 0; see #8605, #14207
                                        xhr.status,
                                        xhr.statusText
                                    );
                                }
                            } else {
                                complete(
                                    xhrSuccessStatus[ xhr.status ] || xhr.status,
                                    xhr.statusText,

                                    // Support: IE <=9 only
                                    // IE9 has no XHR2 but throws on binary (trac-11426)
                                    // For XHR2 non-text, let the caller handle it (gh-2498)
                                    ( xhr.responseType || "text" ) !== "text"  ||
                                    typeof xhr.responseText !== "string" ?
                                        { binary: xhr.response } :
                                        { text: xhr.responseText },
                                    xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    };
                };

                // Listen to events
                xhr.onload = callback();
                errorCallback = xhr.onerror = xhr.ontimeout = callback( "error" );

                // Support: IE 9 only
                // Use onreadystatechange to replace onabort
                // to handle uncaught aborts
                if ( xhr.onabort !== undefined ) {
                    xhr.onabort = errorCallback;
                } else {
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        // Check readyState before timeout as it changes
                        if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {

                            // Allow onerror to be called first,
                            // but that will not handle a native abort
                            // Also, save errorCallback to a variable
                            // as xhr.onerror cannot be accessed
                            window.setTimeout( function() {
                                if ( callback ) {
                                    errorCallback();
                                }
                            } );
                        }
                    };
                }

                // Create the abort callback
                callback = callback( "abort" );

                try {

                    // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
LINE 10109                  xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
                } catch ( e ) {

                    // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
                    if ( callback ) {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            },

            abort: function() {
                if ( callback ) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        };
    }
} );
```

Comment: you should debug your code, and then, when you have understood where is the actual problem, post a minimal reproducible example, more concise and focus than this long question that most likely nobody will read